# By Using TableLayoutPanel label text value is displaying half only using window form c#

Tags: c#, label, tablelayoutpanel

By Using TableLayoutPanel label text value is displaying half only here is my code

```
       lblQuestion.Text += dt.Rows[r]["Question"].ToString();
       tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lblQuestion);
```

while debugging i am getting entire text but while i displaying getting only half of the text into label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
lblQuestion.Text += dt.Rows[r]["Question"].ToString();
lblQuestion.AutoSize = true;
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lblQuestion);
```